# How do I pull the string before and after a specific string in a list without going out of index range?

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have the following list:

```
x = ['i like cats', 'i like dogs', 'i like both']
```

I want to find the string with the word 'dogs' in it and then concatenate the string before and after it to form the sequence "i like cats. i like dogs. i like both." I do it with the following:

```
for position in range(len(x)):
    if 'dogs' in x[position]:
        print x[position - 1] + ". " + x[position] + ". " + x[position + 1] + "."
```

I run into problems when I look for a string that's at the end of a list like this for example:

```
for position in range(len(x)):
    if 'both' in x[position]:
        print x[position - 1] + ". " + x[position] + ". " + x[position + 1] + "."
```

When I do that I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's the best way to do this so that if the string is at the very end of the list, it ignores the index after it so that in the example provided it would print out "i like dogs. i like both"? Furthermore, if I were to look for the string with the word 'cats' in it like this:

```
 for position in range(len(x)):
        if 'cats' in x[position]:
            print x[position - 1] + ". " + x[position] + ". " + x[position + 1] + "."
```

it prints out "i like both. i like cats. i like dogs." I want it to print out "i like cats. i like dogs."

I'm pulling large amounts of text from websites and dumping individual strings into lists so that I can find linguistic patterns and write them to files, so I need to be able to ignore the beginnings and ends of lists.

Comment: you need to use enumerate and elif stmts.

Comment: @Avinash no need for ugly elif if empty strings are added in front and on the back of the last ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a try with my solution as following. It works for all of your situations.

```
x = ['i like cats', 'i like dogs', 'i like both']

for position in range(len(x)):
    if 'cats' in x[position]:
        print ".".join([x[pos] for pos in range(position-1, position+2) if pos in range(0, len(x))]) + "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if position is equal to len(x). If it is then

```
print x[position - 1] + ". " + x[position] + "."
```

otherwise print the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Use list slicing.  If the array indices are out of bounds, it will automatically truncate it at the end.

```
x = ['i like cats', 'i like dogs', 'i like both']
for position in range(len(x)):
    if 'both' in x[position]:
        print ('.'.join([ele for ele in x[0:2]]) if position==0 else '.'.join([ele for ele in x[position-1:position+2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine(items, target):
    result = []
    for index, value in enumerate(items):
        if target in value:
            result.append('. '.join(items[0:2]) if index == 0 else '. '.join(items[index-1:index+2]))
    return result
```

using list `slice` to get the target's previous and next items. If the index is larger than the length, python just ignore it, without throwing an error. using `enumerate` to iterate the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> x = ['i like python', 'i like cats', 'i like dogs', 'i like both']

>>> def concat(term, x):
...     for a in x:
...         i = x.index(a)
...         if term in a and i+1 < len(x):
...             return '. '.join([ x[i-1], a, x[i+1] ])
...         elif term in a:
...             return '. '.join([ x[i-1], a ])

>>> # check
>>> concat('dogs', x)
'i like cats. i like dogs. i like both'
>>> concat('both', x)
'i like dogs. i like both'
```

**another option (with `try except` )**

```
>>> def concat(term, x):
...     for a in x:
...         if term in a:
...             i = x.index(a)
...             try:
...                 return '. '.join([x[i-1], a, x[i+1]])
...             except IndexError:
...                 return '. '.join([x[i-1], a])

>>> # check
>>> concat('dogs', x)
'i like cats. i like dogs. i like both'
>>> concat('both', x)
'i like dogs. i like both'
```